# Add multiple custom data arrays to cart item on WooCommerce custom Ajax add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, cart

So currently have enabled in WooCommerce a custom Ajax add to cart via admin that allows me to add custom additional data as follows:

```
$cart->add_to_cart($product_id , 1, 0, $variation, array('tmcartepo'=>$extra_options_data  ) );
```

And it works nicely.

But the problem is, I need to set 2 (two) arrays of custom additional data on `add_to_cart()`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Basically, this site has Product designer and extra custom fields for products, all managed by separate plugins. My task is to create single product reorder in my account. So, I want to add new product to cart and set two different arrays with metadata for that product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$extra_options_data` variable is an array you can embed it in another array, which will allow to add a 2nd `$extra_options_data_2` variable array like:

```php
$custom_data = array( 'tmcartepo'=> array( 
    'option1' => $extra_options_data,
    'option2' => $extra_options_data_2,
) );

$cart->add_to_cart( $product_id , 1, 0, array(), $custom_data );
```

Then on cart items you will access both as follows:

```php
// Loop through cart items
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    // Access first custom data array
    if( isset($cart_item['tmcartepo']['option1']) && ! empty($cart_item['tmcartepo']['option1']) ) {
        $extra_options_data = $cart_item['tmcartepo']['option1'];
    }

    // Access Second custom data array
    if( isset($cart_item['tmcartepo']['option1']) && ! empty($cart_item['tmcartepo']['option1']) ) {
        $extra_options_data_2 = $cart_item['tmcartepo']['option2'];
    }
}
```

---

Or you can also use it as follows:

```php
$custom_data = array( 
    'tmcartepo'  => $extra_options_data,
    'tmcartepo2' => $extra_options_data_2,
);
```

Then on cart items you will access both as follows:

```php
// Loop through cart items
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    // Access first custom data array
    if( isset($cart_item['tmcartepo']) && ! empty($cart_item['tmcartepo']) ) {
        $extra_options_data = $cart_item['tmcartepo'];
    }

    // Access Second custom data array
    if( isset($cart_item['tmcartepo2']) && ! empty($cart_item['tmcartepo2']) ) {
        $extra_options_data_2 = $cart_item['tmcartepo2'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, have no idea why I haven't' thought of it before, sending two arrays like that solved the problem.